# A problem on countabiliy and families of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $X$ be a non-empty set and $(A_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in \Delta } $ be a family of subsets of $X$.
>
> a) $ \Delta $ is countable and $(A_{\lambda}$ is countable for each
>    $\lambda\in \Delta) \implies \prod_{\lambda\in \Delta} A_{\lambda} $
>    is countable
>
> b) $ \Delta $ is countable and $(A_{\lambda}$ is countable for each
>    $\lambda\in \Delta) \implies \bigcup_{\lambda\in \Delta} A_{\lambda} $ is countable
>
> c) $\bigcup_{\lambda\in \Delta} A_{\lambda} $ is countable $\implies \Delta$ is countable
>
> d) $\prod_{\lambda\in \Delta} A_{\lambda} \neq \emptyset \implies A_{\lambda} \neq \emptyset $ for each $\lambda \in \Delta $
>
> e) $\rho = \{(x,y)\mid x,y \in A_{\lambda} \text{ for some $\lambda \in \Delta$}\}$ is an equivalence relation
>
> Which of these statements are true?

I have very little knowledge on countability as it was barely taught so please help on this. I can only get that b) is true and also think e) is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I will be assuming the axiom of choice throughout, as it’s clear from context that you’re expected to do so.)

You are correct in thinking that (b) is true.

(a) is not necessarily true. Take $\Delta=\Bbb N$ and $A_n=\{0,1\}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Then $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n$ is the set of functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\{0,1\}$. There is a bijection between this set of functions and $\wp(\Bbb N)$, the set of subsets of $\Bbb N$: a set $S\subseteq\Bbb N$ corresponds to its [*indicator* (or *characteristic*) *function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) $\chi_S$. Since $|\wp(\Bbb N)|>|\Bbb N|$, in this case the product set is uncountable.

(c) is not necessarily true even if the sets $A_\lambda$ are required to be non-empty: we might have $\Delta=\Bbb R$, an uncountable set, and $A_\lambda=\{0\}=X$ for each $\lambda\in\Bbb R$, in which case $\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Bbb R}A_\lambda=\{0\}$, which is certainly countable even though $\Bbb R$ is not. For that matter, we could let $X=\Bbb N$, $\Delta=\wp(\Bbb N)$, and $A_\lambda=\lambda$ for each $\lambda\subseteq\Bbb N$. Then $\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Delta}A_\lambda=\Bbb N$, which is countable, but $\Delta=\wp(\Bbb N)$ is uncountable.

(d) is true: if even one $A_\lambda$ is empty, then so is $\prod_{\lambda\in\Delta}A_\lambda$. This is because an element $x$ of $\prod_{\lambda\in\Delta}A_\lambda$ is by definition a function with domain $\Delta$ such that $x(\lambda)\in A_\lambda$ for each $\lambda\in\Delta$. If some $A_\lambda=\varnothing$, there clearly are no such functions.

(e) is true if, for instance, the sets $A_\lambda$ are pairwise disjoint, but in general it need not be true. For instance, let $\Delta=\{0,1\}$, let $A_0=\{0,1\}$, and let $A_1=\{1,2\}$. Then

$$\rho=\{\langle 0,0\rangle,\langle 1,1\rangle,\langle 2,2\rangle,\langle 0,1\rangle,\langle 1,0\rangle,\langle 1,2\rangle,\langle 2,1\rangle\}\;.$$ This relation is certainly reflexive and symmetric, as indeed it will always be, but in this case it’s not transitive: $\langle 0,1\rangle\in\rho$ and $\langle 1,2\rangle\in\rho$, but $\langle 0,2\rangle\notin\rho$.

Answer (score 1):

Things that you *may* know about countable sets, and otherwise:

1. $\Bbb N$ is countable. Every countable set has an injective function into $\Bbb N$, and if it is infinite (some include finite sets as countable) then there is a bijection between $\Bbb N$ and the set as well.
2. $2^\Bbb N$ is uncountable. It is the cardinality of the real numbers, and the cardinality of the power set of $\Bbb N$. Taking $A^B$ is the same the product of $B$ copies of $A$. Similarly $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$ is similar to taking a countable product of the set $\{0,1\}$.
3. $f\in\prod_{\lambda\in\Delta} A_\lambda$ means that $f$ is a function from $\Delta$ such that $f(\lambda)\in A_\lambda$, for all $\lambda\in\Delta$.
4. A collection of subsets of $X$ is an equivalence relation on a subset of $X$ if and only if the sets are pairwise disjoint. This is the content of the fundamental theorem connecting equivalence relations and partitions.

This should be enough to conclude that only $b$ and $d$ are true. Can you prove why, and can you come up with counterexamples for the rest of the statements?

Comment: There seems to be a typo in 2.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Is there?

Comment: "It is the cardinality of the real numbers, as ***the the*** cardinality of the power set of $\Bbb N$."

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I blame the very little sleep I had, and the fact that someone is banging hammers and drilling somewhere nearby... So I can't get back to sleep either.